# Given $g(x) = x^2 + 2x$, evaluate $\frac {g(x) - g(a)}{x - a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Just not seeing where I am making a mistake here.

> With $g(x) = x^2 + 2x$, why does $\dfrac {g(x) - g(a)}{x - a}$ evaluate to $x + a + 2$?

I thought that I could immediately cancel an x and a from the denominator so I set it up this way.

> Plugging in we get, $\frac{(x^2+2x)-(a^2+2a)}{x-a}$. Did I miss a cue to factor? I immediately though to rewrite it like this, $\frac{(xx+2x)-(aa+2a)}{x-a}$

In this form I thought I could then cancel an $x$ and a $-a$, which led me to

> $3x-3a$

Cheers!

Comment: *"Did I miss a cue to factor?"* Yes! :) ... *"In this form I thought I could then cancel an $x$ and a $-a$"* No! :) ... You can only cancel a *factor* of the numerator with a *factor* of the denominator. The $x$ at that stage is a factor of *part* of the numerator, but that doesn't count, and $x$ isn't a factor of the denominator, either; likewise for the $-a$. So, since canceling only works with factors, you need to take the cue and *factor* the numerator ... the *entire* numerator, not just individual parts of it. Can you rewrite the numerator to look like "$(x-a)(\text{stuff})$"?

Comment: @Blue so when you do the factor, do you think first to pull out an x, and then -a? Or do you try to do both at the same time? I tried to do the former, and then I got stuck because there was a -2 floating around that I didn't know what to do with. I don't have a good factoring strategy as I haven't done algebra in years. This seems to be the problem. I just found a college algebra textbook on openstax so I think that should be sufficient practice. Any recommendations on how or where to practice factoring would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @jwright: Factoring can be tricky, so get all the practice you can. (You can also go to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5B%28x%5E2%2B2x%29-%28a%5E2%2B2a%29%5D).) Here, gather similar terms $x^2$ and $-a^2$, and $2x$ and $-2a$ (note the negatives). Then you have $x^2-a^2=(x-a)(x+a)$ ("difference of squares") and $2x-2a=2(x-a)$, so the whole numerator is $(x-a)(x+a)+2(x-a)$. Thus, $x-a$ is a factor you can pull out, leaving $x+a$ from the first group, and $2$ from the second: ie, $(x-a)(x+a+2)$. The problem has you cancel $x-a$ with the denominator, leaving $x+a+2$.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac {g(x) - g(a)}{x - a}=\frac{x^2+2x-a^2-2a}{x-a}=\frac{(x-a)(x+a+2)}{x-a}$. Assuming $x-a\not =0$ then this gives you the answer. Note the factorisation is natural in the sense that $x=a$ is a root to the polynomial $x^2+2x-a^2-2a$

Answer (score 1):

Given $$g(x)=x^{2}+2x$$
Note where the x's are. If we were to take $g(a)$, you would be replacing the $x$'s in the equation with $a$'s.

So it follows $$g(a)=a^{2}+2a$$
Plugging into the equation you were given, you would find that $$\frac{(x^{2}+2x)-(a^{2}+2a)}{x-a}$$

From here, try working with your numerator and finding a like term to cancel out your denominator. Hope this helps!